# Abort threads associated with Unreferenced Objects

Tags: c#

I am working on a form in this form when user clicks a button a new thread is generated that Created a new form and do some work and show the result. See thee following code
I have made the main class in my project that stores the references of each type of object

Program.someFormReference

When user click the button a new thread creates  and 
Program.someFormReference=new CreatedForm().
Now what will be if user presses button more than once.We have more than one objects in memory with threads working on them. But I had reference to  only one thread.
One solution to avoid this situation is to make button disable until thread completes it,s works.
What other solution can be to avoid this uncontrolled thread chain.

Comment: The code you mentioned seems to be missing. Also, if you are using Windows Forms, you should not create a form within any thread except the main UI thread.

Comment: @Adrian: It's fine for other threads to create their own message pumps for their own top-level windows. That's typically what happens with a splash screen, for example.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To be able to create multiple forms within their own threads or to make sure only one form exists at a time?

Comment: Fine when user clicks on button i create a new thread it start working and we create a new form which tells user to wait.And we set it to Program.someFormRefrence.I use this refrence(Program.someFormRefrence)to hide (please wait form) when thread complete working.But if user clicks more than once i have more than one form showing but i had the refrence of only one form.How to hide other forms when i had not refrence of them.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do first is to decide on the following question:

**Do you want to have one or many such threads active?**

It seems you are undecided on that issue so figure that one out first.

Then, if: **I want to have only one thread active**, then you either:

1. Disallow starting another thread until the first one is finished
2. Stop the active one before starting a new

To stop the active one, if it is running a form, simply close that form. ie. if you have this in your thread:

```
Application.Run(someform);
```

then close that form. You need to use `someform.Invoke` because it is running on another thread but that should work just as you want.

Or, if: **I want to have many such threads active**, then you need to keep a list of active threads around, and manage this list, ie. remove entries when threads finish, etc.